# Searching TokenStream fields in Lucene

Tags: c#, .net, lucene, lucene.net

I am just starting out with Lucene, and I feel like I must have a fundamental misunderstanding of it, but from the samples and documentation I could not figure out this issue.

I cannot seem to get Lucene to return results for fields which are initialized with a `TokenStream`, whereas fields initialized with a `string` work fine. I am using Lucene.NET 2.9.2 RC2.

[Edit] I've also tried this with the latest Java version (3.0.3) and see the same behavior, so it is not some quirk of the port.

Here is a basic example:

```
Directory index = new RAMDirectory();
Document doc = new Document();
doc.Add(new Field("fieldName", new StandardTokenizer(new StringReader("Field Value Goes Here"))));
IndexWriter iw = new IndexWriter(index, new StandardAnalyzer());
iw.AddDocument(doc);
iw.Commit();
iw.Close();
Query q = new QueryParser("fieldName", new StandardAnalyzer()).Parse("value");
IndexSearcher searcher = new IndexSearcher(index, true);
Console.WriteLine(searcher.Search(q).Length());
```

(I realize this uses APIs deprecated with 2.9, but that's just for brevity... pretend the arguments that specify the version are there and I use one of the new `Search`s).

This returns no results.

However, if I replace the line that adds the field with

```
doc.Add(new Field("fieldName", "Field Value Goes Here", Field.Store.NO, Field.Index.ANALYZED));
```

then the query returns a hit, as I would expect. It also works if I use the `TextReader` version.

Both fields are indexed and tokenized, with (I think) the same tokenizer/analyzer (I've also tried others), and neither are stored, so my intuition is that they should behave the same. What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found the answer to be casing.

The token stream created by `StandardAnalyzer` has a `LowerCaseFilter` while creating the `StandardTokenizer` directly does not apply such a filter.

Comment: not only that but StandardAnalyzer also filters out common english StopWords via a StopFilter. The rule of thumb with Lucene is to search and index with the exact same setup of TokenStreams on both side. In your code you should not instanciate StandardTokenizer directly, but use StandardAnalyzer.TokenStream() to create it